# Add Replacing url php

Tags: php, url, preg-replace

hello I want replace following phrase:

`tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/plugins/emotions/img/smiley-cool.gif`

with:

`http://mysite.com/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/plugins/emotions/img/smiley-cool.gif`

I have tried :

```
$comments = preg_replace ("tinymce/", "http://mysite.com/tinymce/", $comments);
```

but i get an error:

```
warning Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash
```

can you help me?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`str_replace`](http://php.net/str_replace).

```
$comments = str_replace ("tinymce/", "http://mysite.com/tinymce/", $comments);
```

just be very careful with this: It's a very primitive method. For example, if you run it twice, it will replace the occurrence in the already correct `http://mysite.com/tinymce/`, breaking the link in the process.

Answer (score 2):

The first parameter of `preg_replace` functions must be a regular expression (regex) delimited by a character of your choice.
For example you should do :

```
$comments = preg_replace ("`tinymce/`", "http://mysite.com/tinymce/", $comments);
```

You may also use output buffering (with ob_start) to apply rewrite function on all url or anything you want.

http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php

And try to match a real expression, here you could use str_replace, but if you write tinymce/ in a comment then it will be replaced too.

Answer (score 2):

`preg_replace` expects the first parameter to be a regular expression
all regular expressions needs to be inside delimeters for example `/regex/`

so if you want your code to work you have to change your regex to `/tinymce\//` (and escape the forward slash) or use a different delimeter like `@tinymce/@`

Answer (score 0):

Read about basics of regular expressions in PHP (pattern has to begin and end with defined character ex. @ (after that come flags)) or use function str_replace